# Using htaccess modrewrite for friendly urls gives a 404 error

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I am trying to rewrite

http://example.com/category/this-is-my-category

to...

http://example.com/category.php?id=this-is-my-category

My .htaccess file is below:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^category/(\d+)/([\w-]+)$ /category.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This gives a 404 error

http://example.com/category.php exists on the server

I have also tried

```
RewriteRule ^category/(\d+)/([\w-]+)$ ./category.php?id=$1 [L]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^/category/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /category.php?id=$1
```

I have read some articles on this and can't see an issue with the code in the .htaccess file.

Comment: FYI, it's actually the other way around... you want to rewrite the _nice_ URL to the real one

Comment: What URL are you using to test? Is it literally `/category/this-is-my-category`?

Comment: Thanks. im using...

http://example.com/category/this-is-my-category to test

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right, so your first regex...

```
^category/(\d+)/([\w-]+)$
```

requires a number between `category` and the last part, eg `/category/1234/something-else`.

Your second regex...

```
^/category/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$
```

has an incorrect leading slash (rewrite rules start at the rewrite-base) and requires **only** letters and numbers after `category`, eg `/category/thisIsMyCategory`.

The URL you're testing has letters and hyphens.

To me, it looks like you want

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^category/([\w-]+)$ /category.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Demo ~ https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=8c3de5aa-68f3-5ec0-9c69-23ff2dbe2d6e

---

Some notes...

- It's rare to ever need `RewriteBase`, especially if your `.htaccess` file is in the root directory so I've removed it
- I've added the `QSA` flag so any query parameters are preserved. For example

  ```
  /category/this-is-my-category?foo=bar
  ```

  becomes

  ```
  /category.php?id=this-is-my-category&foo=bar
  ```